# Set a custom background color to the button

Tags: css, materialize

What is the correct way to change the color of a button ?
My button :

```
<button id="easy_mode" href="#gameZone" class="btn waves-effect waves-light spacing theme-color" >
```

Theme color:

```
.theme-color {
    background-color: #ee6e73;
}

.theme-color:hover {
    background-color: #F18B8F;
}
```

the button loses the color after it has been clicked. What am i missing ?

Comment: What do you really want to obtain ? For the "hover" color to stay after a click use `.theme-color:hover,.theme-color:focus`

Comment: Are you sure none of the other classes are affecting the colour of the button? It works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/0j4vg6yr/

Comment: I tried focus before, traced it back with undo, made a spelling mistake....Dammn my bad...Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working fine. I'm guessing you made a small PEBKAC mistake somewhere. Might want to check your HTML and CSS real quick to see if there are no typos anywhere.

```css
.theme-color {
    background-color: #ee6e73;
}

.theme-color:hover {
    background-color: #F18B8F;
}
```

```html
<button id="easy_mode" href="#gameZone" class="btn waves-effect waves-light spacing theme-color">Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <button id="easy_mode" href="#gameZone" class="btn waves-effect waves-light spacing theme-color" >text</button>



    .theme-color {
        background-color: #ee6e73;
        border:none;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    .theme-color:hover {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border:none;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
```

Try these html and css codes

You can check here
https://jsfiddle.net/kyfycnn7/